# Where can an absolute beginner of Kohana PHP go to learn how to use it from the ground up?

Tags: php, kohana

I have a month of free time and I've decided to launch my own website. It's going to be big and have dymanic content where different users with different roles can perform modifications to the site. Place comments, rate stores, list items, etc.

This sound like a **perfect** opportunity for me to expand my horizons and learn a PHP Framework.

I've used PHP bare bones before but nothing too complex.

As of now, do you think Kohana is a mature framework to use? I've used Zend in the past for a course in Uni but it sucked **horribly**, I was new to the MVC model, but Zend had pretty much zero workable tutorials and guides for newbies. That's why I hated it.

Where can I go to learn how to use Kohana from a retarded starting point?

Thank you very much for your time.

**Edit:**
While documentation is nice, it's not really what I'm looking for. I learn much quicker when there is a step by step guide on how to build a functioning website example, with theory pasted as side text to what is being done in that step.

Is there anything like that in existance?

Comment: You sure you want to build something this complex with a framework you've never used over the course of only one month?

Comment: Absolutely. It's not a Uni course, it's a project that's based on my idea and generally speaking when I work on something I like I put much more into it.

Comment: Isn't it easier to start with an open source CMS?

Comment: Of course it is, but that's not the point. I want to learn something new and dives balls deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going the Kohana 3.0 route there's an [unofficial wiki](http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php) with examples and the [official documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.kohana).

The official documentation is currently a work in progress, while the wiki has links to tutorials and explains how to start with kohana.

Comment: the link you posted to the unofficial wiki looks like it has changed.  You can find it here: http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php

Answer (score 2):

I would checkout the repository and browse the website source; it's an excellent resource of examples.

Other than that, if you want to know how to use something, look at the source for the helper/library/core file in question. Source code is the best instructor.

(this is coming from a dev)

Comment: I agree with this in general, but it probably isn't the best way to *start* learning a framework. It's better to do this when you are comfortable with the basics. Anyway, I'll give you +1 to offset the negative.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a site which went from Kohana 2.3.4 to Kohana 3.0. I suggest go for version 3. If you have foundations in basic website operations with PHP (image uploads, session management, user authentication, CRUD etc), learning KOhana will be a breeze.

For a fast-paced run-through with the basics, go to this site: http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php

go through that and if you can't understand one or two things from it, search it in the forums.

P.S. Kohana is mature enough for huge projects. But Kohana is just a tool, in the end the website will rely on your skills as a developer. Good luck in using Kohana :)

Answer (score 0):

you will find user guide and reference [here](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/).

Also you can find Kohama's community and forums links for [here](http://kohanaframework.org/community)

This could help you in great deal.